# Using Request Headers in Query/Mutation

Tags: hasura

I am following Hasura basic tutorial on creating a todo app https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/hasura-advanced/introduction/ and want to extend it and have few additional operations, but don't seem to be able. Setup is as in the tutorial - you have `Tasks` table with `title`, `description`, `authorId`, `isComplete`, `isPublic` column. Table permissions are setup as in the tutorial, so a user can only select their own or public tasks. They can also update only their own tasks. Operations I want to add:

1. Query only public tasks that are NOT theirs (additionally, inverse also - only theirs without public ones).
2. Mutate public tasks to complete that are not theirs (update `isComplete` without having permissions to other columns).

I could create views for the first case, but it seems too much of an effort for such a simple logic. I think both cases could simply be done with access to Request Header (`x-hasura-user-id`)  like so:

```
query PublicTasksOnly {
  tasks(where: {isPublic: {_eq: true}, authorId: {_neq: x-hasura-user-id}}) {
    description
    isComplete
    title
  }
}
```

But it seems that this is not possible. Any ideas/suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge I do not think it is possible to reference http headers in your graphql queries. Have you tried passing the `userId` as a variable to the query? Something like the following:

```
query PublicTasksOnly($userId: String!) {
  tasks(where: {isPublic: {_eq: true}, authorId: {_neq: $userId}}) {
    description
    isComplete
    title
  }
}
```

Comment: Did not try it, but I also though about this approach. Seems like an anti-pattern. Sending duplicate `userId` when you're already using JWT for auth. Also, seems like a security risk - in the second example an authorized user can mutate another users public task by faking `userId` in a request.

Comment: There is no security risk.  The userId variable is just used to filter out the allowed data. If you also want to store who mutated the public task to isComplete= true, you can use 'presets' in the permissions to take userId from jwt.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want to achieve but if your problem gets solved by adding this header `x-hasura-user-id` then I can help you out.

You can copy the `graphql endpoint from hasura console` and hit simple `http` request to that endpoint with query and it's variables in request body. Sharing sample code here using http library `axios`:

```js
   



import axios from 'axios';
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://your-hasura-project-url.hasura.app/v1/graphql',
  headers: { 'x-hasura-user-id': '< Your user id >' },
  data: {
    query: `query PublicTasksOnly {
             tasks(where: {isPublic: {_eq: true}}) {
             description
             isComplete
             title
            }
           }`,
    variables: { userId: 'abc-xyz' }
  }
})
```

This should solve your issue.